# MongoDB delete document inside a collection by NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So what I'm trying to do, if you take a look at the picture bellow, is to delete just one document inside `transactions` by it's id.

[image]

What I have tried:

```
const result = await db.updateMany({ pipedrive_id: 999 }, { $pull: { transactions: { id: id } } });
```

As suggested in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738353/delete-inside-a-document-mongodb). But it didn't do anything.

Then I tried:

```
const result = await db.findOneAndDelete(
  {
    'transactions._id': { $in: id },
  }
);
```

Where `id` in both cases is the `_id` of the transaction inside `transactions`. But this didn't work as expected as it deleted everything all items in the collection and the parent as well.

So I'm kinda stuck, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the answer you are trying to follow doesn't works. (Also the comment in the answer is correct). Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bq7i1TtPuXN) and how it fails.

As explained, for example in the Node.JS Driver Jira Ticket [$pull operator doesn't work with dot notation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1081)

> this is expected behavior, and simply is not currently supported by the query language.

So you need this query:

```
db.updateOne({
  "_id": 1,
  "transactions._id": 1
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "transactions": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
})
```

Note how in the `$pull` object there is not dot notation, is defined the object itself.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zab8lzFtIYu)

Answer (score 0):

So, I kinda achieved my goal, but I'm betting there's proper mongodb solution to this. This is just hacky way to do it I guess.

```
// fetch all documents inside transactions collection
const queryResult = await db.find({ pipedrive_id: 999 });
const idToRemove = 'some id';

if (queryResult.length) {
// filter out the ID's that needs to be deleted
const results = queryResult.transactions.filter((item) => idToRemove !== item['id']);

// update the document with the filtered ones (aka deleting the specified ones)
await db.updateOne(
  {
    pipedrive_id: 999
  },
  {
    $set: { transactions: results },
  }
)
```